# How to keep 2 "columns" in mongodb unique

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am merging business databases.

So I have data like

```
id1 id2 
id1 id2
id1 id4
id1 id5
id1 id2
id4 id5
id4 id5
id4 id5
id4 id5
```

That sort of thing.

I want to sort that into

```
id1 id2
id1 id4
id1 id5
id1 id2
id4 id5
```

So basically if first column and the second column is the same than it's duplicate

Do I need duplicate or just compound indexes with unique attribute will suffice? If so what would be the format of the index.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I think a unique compound index will do.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({first_column: 1, second_column: 1}, {unique: true});
```

**[UPDATE](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#db.collection.ensureIndex)**: Deprecated since version 3.0.0: db.collection.ensureIndex() is now an alias for db.collection.createIndex().
Use [`db.collection.createIndex()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex) rather than `db.collection.ensureIndex()` to create new indexes.